# __str__ function of class ported from rust to python using pyo3 doesn't get used in print

Tags: python, object, rust, cpython

I am using the `pyo3` rust crate (version `0.11.1`) in order to port rust code, into cpython (version `3.8.2`) code. I have created a class called `my_class` and defined the following functions: `new`, `__str__`, and `__repr__`.

> **TL;DR**: The `__str__` function exists on a class ported from rust using the pyo3 crate, but doesn't get printed when just using `print(obj)`, and instead having to write `print(obj.__str__())`

The `my_class` definition is here:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
struct my_class {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    num: i32,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    debug: bool,
}

#[pymethods]
impl my_class {
    #[new]
    fn new(num: i32, debug: bool) -> Self {
        my_class {num, debug}
    }
    fn __str__(&self) -> PyResult<String>   {
        Ok(format!("[__str__] Num: {}, Debug: {}", self.num, self.debug))
    }

    fn __repr__(&self) -> PyResult<String> {
        Ok(format!("[__repr__] Num: {}, Debug: {}", self.num, self.debug))
    }
}

#[pymodule]
fn pymspdb(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<my_class>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

I build this (into release mode), and test the code with the following code:

```py
from my_module import my_class

def main():
    dsa = my_class(1, True)
    print(dsa)
    print(dsa.__str__())
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running the test python code, I get the following output:

```
<my_class object at 0x7fb7828ae950>
[__str__] Num: 1, Debug: true
```

Now I have thought of possible solutions to this. One solution might be the pyo3 rust crate actually acts as a proxy, and in order to port classes into python might implement some sort of object which transfers all actions over to the ported class. So it might not implement its own `__str__` therefore not giving me what I want.
The second possible solution I thought of was I might not be overloading the `__str__` function properly, therefore when python tries to use the print function it doesn't access the correct function and just does the default behavior.

Thanks for reading so far, hope I can find an answer since I didn't find anything online for this.

Comment: The chain of calls is `print` -> `str` -> `__str__`. What does `print(str(dsa))` output?

Comment: Well, print(str(dsa)) prints `<my_class object at 0x7fb7828ae950>`, but the `str` function should call the `__str__` function internally shouldn't it? According to the documentation "If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns object.__str__()...", here we don't have any encoding nor errors so it matches the description

Comment: The proxy object theory sounds plausible: What you see seems to be just a generic `__repr__()` of `my_class`... print should try to call perform `__str__()` conversion, but fail over to `__repr__()` if not defined.

Comment: @OndrejK.Yup, that's exactly why I'm so conflicted on this matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because you need to implement these methods through the [`PyObjectProtocol` trait](https://pyo3.rs/master/class.html#basic-object-customization).

Many Python `__magic__` methods correspond to C-level [function pointer slots](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html) in a type object's memory layout. A type implemented in C needs to provide a function pointer in the slot, and Python will automatically generate a method to wrap the pointer for explicit method calls. A type implemented in Python will automatically have function pointers inserted that delegate to the magic methods.

The Python internals will usually look for the function pointer rather than the corresponding magic method, and if Python doesn't find the function pointer, it will behave as though the method doesn't exist. That's why, for example, you had to use `#[new]` to mark your constructor instead of implementing a `__new__` static method.

`__str__` and `__repr__` also correspond to function pointers - specifically, [`tp_str`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_str) and [`tp_repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_repr). If you just try to implement them as regular methods, pyo3 won't generate the function pointers needed. `PyObjectProtocol` is the pyo3 interface to go through for that.

Comment: That's exactly it! I just found it as well, thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: @fdsa: Rather than editing the code in the question, it's better to post an answer for that. Editing the question makes it hard to tell what the problem was and what the answers were trying to fix.

Comment: Yup, I inserted it at the bottom :)

Comment: @fdsa i think they mean as an actual answer rather than as an addendum to the question, so that people looking at the question know where to look for the answer, and others can up/downvote

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution…

The python importing the rust code…

```
from my_module import my_class

def main():
    dsa = my_class(1, True)
    print(dsa)
    print(dsa.__str__())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The rust source code…

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::PyObjectProtocol;

#[pyclass]
struct my_class {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    num: i32,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    debug: bool,
}

#[pymethods]
impl my_class {
    #[new]
    fn new(num: i32, debug: bool) -> Self {
        my_class {num, debug}
    }
    fn __str__(&self) -> PyResult<String>   {
        Ok(format!("[__str__] Num: {}, Debug: {}", self.num, self.debug))
    }

    fn __repr__(&self) -> PyResult<String> {
        Ok(format!("[__repr__] Num: {}, Debug: {}", self.num, self.debug))
    }
}

#[pyproto]
impl PyObjectProtocol for my_class {
    fn __str__(&self) -> PyResult<String>   {
        Ok(format!("[__str__] Num: {}, Debug: {}", self.num, self.debug))
    }

    fn __repr__(&self) -> PyResult<String> {
        Ok(format!("[__repr__] Num: {}, Debug: {}", self.num, self.debug))
    }
}

#[pymodule]
fn pymspdb(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<my_class>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```